Can these two questions about otherworldly typos be merged?
It looks like I asked substantively the same question twice (albeit using different examples).
What is the earliest example of an author using an apparent typo to indicate that the story does not actually take place in our world?
What was the first work to use misspelled words to indicate that it took place in a fictional world?
Can they be merged?

Technically this doesn't need a meta question: you can dupe-close all by yourself (VTC as a high-rep user, then as the OP you have the option to close directly), then raise a mod flag for a merge. Anyway, done - your notifications may be a bit buggy as the comments on the new post got shifted to the old one, but everything's in one place now, minus the comments about it being a dupe.

@Randal'Thor Yeah, I figured I could it without posting this, but I discovered the duplication while my computer was rebooting, and I figured doing it on my phone would have been awkward.
